# Php logging, error-log, and customization

Tags: php, logging, large-files

I have a large enterprise scale php app with lots of calls to error_log.

I think, at times, when exceptions are being thrown, the error log fills up the disk an causes server issues.

How can I better utilize my logging utilities in php? In particular I don't know much about how the error_log functionalith of php is managed and used in the real world.

Are there other logging mechanisms that are more appropriate? Like an info_log or a log expiration utility that will delete/rotate log files once they get too large?  Finally, can I have multiple log files?

Comment: Isin't the best way would be to fix problem's in your php ?

Comment: No - because there is no way to verify that ALL problems have been fixed. Low priority, repetetive Error Logs should never interfere with the ability of a server to stay alive.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a log-rotator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, error_log is good enough and provide us with sufficient functionality. Yes you can have multiple log files, you just need to manage them.:)
For example, you can use something like this:

```
ini_set('error_log','my_error_file.log');
```

And about auto deleting thing, I think there is no advantage of using error_log, if you really want to do auto delete. You should rather dump them somewhere, or just turn logging off/minimal using error_reporting in php.ini.

And finally, you can write your own logging class, which is really very simple and fantastic solution, because it will be very short snippet of code, and can really work according to your will. I usually do the same.
Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing as such, but there is a syslog function available, though I never found it useful. It generates system log message.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for starters, not all errors should be logged. If an error can be handeled within the software (90% of them should be and the other 50% [sorry Russians :P] should be non-existent). Only a small portion (related to input errors) should exists, and those shouldn't be logged anyway.

Use Exceptions instead of relying on errors, Exceptions can be handled, and when they aren't they halt the script. Extend the Exception class to allow more types of exceptions (`InvalidArgumentException`, `MathException`, `LoggedErrorException`), get creative, I've made an entire 30 Exception types library. Just make sure you [do it right!](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php)

Other then that, error_log will log a lot of details, with the use of exceptions, you can log whatever you want. See **[Filesystem Functions](http://il.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)**.

Comment: The part about the exceptions is good. .  However .... I have a long running http streaming connection with a social site - so interrupts are expected... So it's not quite as black and white as you imply.

Comment: In which case, since the interruption is **exceptional**, you should throw and **Exception** and then handle it (log it), you can differentiate it by extending a class to `HTTPStreamingException` and only log that (while other exceptions get a different handler).